# Image Map Creator/Generator that allows for the easy addition Javascript onclick events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, imagemap

While I'm well aware of how image maps work, and how to code them, etc...I find it a waste of time to use the image map creator to generate the Image Map code, then use HTML Tidy to tidy it, and then manually add all of the image attribute adding `onclick` events, having them return false, and making sure that the `href="#"`, especially for large image maps.

Does anyone know of an image map creator that supports adding Javascript events (such as `onclick`) directly as opposed to just adding href urls, and then having to manual edit the code later?

Comment: Why not just write some JavaScript that does all this for you instead of doing it manually? Hooking up event handlers at run-time is not a big deal.

Comment: I just want to do this quick, it's not like for a big project or anything.  I'm using Tiddlywiki and I just want to make some links to tiddler using an image for documentation purposes.  It's easy to create an image map using an image map creation tool, but none of the ones I've found seem to support quick addition of adding Javascript events.  

I know what you are saying is simple to do, but why roll around in the code for something that isn't a program, and could be generated so simply in the same manner as everything else.

Comment: I could probably just edit an existing project and add it in there, but I don't have time for that...I want to get these "visual docs" written for some people.

Comment: I doubt you'll find what you need. Image maps have really fallen out of favour over the years.

Comment: "Image maps have really fallen out of favour over the years" only by people can't see their true inner beauty :) http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to solve this problem the wrong way. This problem has nothing to do with creating image maps, it has to do with manipulating HTML. There's nothing unique about the tags in an imagemap.

So you have a bunch of stuff you want to do to some HTML, which happens to be an imagemap. Why not use something designed specifically to manipulate HTML, e.g. jQuery, to solve your problem?

"adding onclick events, having them return false, and making sure that the href="#"...

```
$('area').attr('href','#');
$('area').attr('onclick','.. whatever you want ...');
```

Just because jQuery is a javascript tool doesn't mean you can't use it for one-time tasks. Right click in Chrome, inspect element, "Copy as HTML."

Now let me add that using jQuery to add `onclick` attributes makes little sense, generally, since you should just be adding event handlers. But you could do this if you wanted to produce HTML that you will then copy/paste as hardcoded HTML. But I generally speaking, "onclick" should be avoided like the plague, especially with (as you say) imagemaps that have a lot of elements. It's just wasted bandwidth; since you're binding javascript handlers anyway you are obviously running javascript on your page already. Why not just use javascript to bind the handlers?

Comment: I didn't waste any bandwidth.  I'm taking notes in a Tiddlywiki.  The Tiddlywiki is on my thumbdrive.  But none the less the points you make are still valid for most situations, thank you for your suggestion.  I'm just trying to do something quickly. ****shrugs****

Comment: Well, yeah, and what does bandwidth mean these days? Not so much about saving a few nanoseconds, generally it's just nicer to bind event handlers from script than hardcode them all. "Unubtrusive html" as they say. But I am sure there are use cases for everything, and I don't know what Tiddlywiki is, so maybe it makes sense in your situation.

Comment: Tiddlywiki is a wiki that doesn't require a server and sits on a thumbdrive.  It's a self-modifying html file.